# Can I apply Groupby on Pandas dataframe and calculate mean across all the columns?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, pandas-groupby

Suppose I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
Category Col1 Col2 Col3 Col4 Col5

Footwear    35   55   67   87   94

Apparels    56   65   54   84   77

Footwear    87   85   56   95   35

Handbags    83   62   724  51   62

Handbags    61   512  21   58   78

Apparels 50   62   172  77   5
```

Now, I want to find the mean and standard deviation for the unique categories, but not for the different columns separately, rather one mean and one std for each category. So I want an output like this:

```
Category mean stdev

Footwear xxx   aaa

Apparels yyy   bbb

Handbags zzz   ccc
```

I cannot just calculate the mean and std first across the columns using mean function with axis=1 and then Groupby for the categories. It would yield incorrect results.

So my dilemma is that I want to perform a groupby, while aggregating across rows and columns at the same time.

I have a feeling that a user-defined function could do it, applying it through lambda aggregation along with Groupby. But I couldn't do it. Am I even on the right track? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, lets try using `melt` and `groupby` with `agg`

```
df1 = pd.melt(df,id_vars='Category').groupby('Category').agg(mean=('value','mean'),
                                                             std=('value','std'))

print(df1)

           mean         std
Category                   
Apparels   70.2   41.983595
Footwear   69.6   23.291391
Handbags  171.2  241.295946
```